# Printing new types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I'm following a tutorial to create a new type. This is my code:

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float
```

When I load the file with ghci and I type:

```
Circle 10 20 5
```

It prints this:

```
<interactive>:29:1:
    No instance for (Show Shape) arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `show` function has type:

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

Which means it only works on things with a `Show` instances.  You can make your types an instance of the `Show` class by either manually defining an instance or letting the compiler automatically derive one:

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float
  deriving (Show)
```

or

```
instance Show Shape where
    show (Circle a b c) = "Circle " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " " ++ show c
    show (Rectangle a b c d) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it typing this in the interpreter:

```
:s -u
```

Comment: This doesn't work here (on GHC 7.10.1). All I get is `IO error:  "-u" does not exist`.

Comment: Yes sorry, it solve the problem with hugs but not in ghci

Comment: Oh is this for a class?  Who's class, Jones?